# How to make my home page very fast?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, memcached, gzip

It works and I want to make it super fast. The [index page](http://montaoproject.appspot.com) is very static, doesn't really change for days unless date updates or a map updates. So it should be possible to optimize to very fast since it doesn't change much. I recently migrated to HRD and my URI is montaoproject.appspot.com I rewrote this so that it is only python and django / html (no data layer trip.) Memcache? Other options? Reduce javascript? I first made sure that data layer isn't touched:

```
def get(self):
    logo = ''
    if get_host().find('.br') > 0:
        cookie_django_language = 'pt-br'
        logo = 'montao'
    elif get_host().find('allt') > 0 and not self.request.get('hl'):
        logo = ''
        cookie_django_language = 'sv'
    elif get_host().find('gralumo') > 0 \
        and not self.request.get('hl'):
        cookie_django_language = 'es_AR'  # learn
    else:
        logo = ''
        cookie_django_language = self.request.get('hl', '')  # edit
    if cookie_django_language:
        if cookie_django_language == 'unset':
            del self.request.COOKIES['django_language']
        else:
            self.request.COOKIES['django_language'] = \
                cookie_django_language
        translation.activate(cookie_django_language)
    loginmsg = ''
    user = users.get_current_user()
    twittername = None
    client = OAuthClient('twitter', self)
    if client.get_cookie():
        info = client.get('/account/verify_credentials')
        twittername = info['screen_name']

    # seconds_valid = 8600
    # self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=%d" % seconds_valid

    if logo == 'montao':
        self.render(
            u'montao',
            host=get_host(),
            twittername=twittername,
            continue_url=get_host(),
            loginmsg=loginmsg,
            form_url=blobstore.create_upload_url('/fileupload'),
            user_url=(api.users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if api.users.get_current_user() else api.users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)),
            admin=users.is_current_user_admin(),
            user=(users.get_current_user() if users.get_current_user() else ''
                  ),
            logo=logo,
            )
    else:
        self.render(
            u'home',
            host=get_host(),
            twittername=twittername,
            continue_url=get_host(),
            loginmsg=loginmsg,
            form_url=blobstore.create_upload_url('/fileupload'),
            latest=Ad.all().filter('published =',
                    True).order('-modified').get(),
            user_url=(api.users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if api.users.get_current_user() else api.users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)),
            admin=users.is_current_user_admin(),
            guser=(users.get_current_user() if users.get_current_user() else ''
                   ),
            logo=logo,
            )
```

Comment: If you're using Django, have you considered reading the Django documentation regarding caching? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/. If you're not using django, have you considered using an off-the-shelf caching tool like Varnish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I'd recommend inverting the page, putting index.html out as a static-file, as well as css and js files, then making an AJAX request to the server to fill in dynamic bits. Static files load really fast.

You might still be able to pull that off, by using client-side JavaScript to figure out which logo and such to use, but getting the file upload form rendered is going to be slower, since the `create_upload_url` needs to happen server side.

Comment: For the basic functions I think I can make everything static. I only require translations and those I can make with static html instead of django translations. `create_upload_url` I can move to another page that really requires scripts. I think the fastest can be make everything static and cache with ETags or likewise. The dynamic bits are like daily updates + logged_in_user.name and those are not basic functions. I also don't require a welcome message for a logged in user "Welcome, {{logged_in_user.name}}` is unnecessary candy when I can make it faster. Or write the welcome message with AJAX.

Comment: I don't think modifying the actions the user's browser has to carry out to accommodate a fairly arbitrary ('static' vs 'dynamic') server-end distinction is a good idea. Instead, you can pre-render content on the server end and serve it to users with very low latency - see [my article](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-1-Static-serving) on the subject for an example.

Comment: Nick and I had a discussion on this, and have agreed to disagree. Pre-rendering is fine if there's no server startup to contend with. If you site gets enough traffic that there's always a live instance, pre-rendering can work. On the other hand, quick-loading static content gives the illusion of quick response. Go with whichever approach works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know python, but if it doesn't change for days I am sure you could write something to convert the above into HTML (say every hour), and then just serve the HTML version. That will give you one of the largest optimisations possible, since your home page then doesn't have to be processed by a script engine at all.

Comment: Yes I can make I cron job that makes an html file. I think it will be very fast then. Thanks a lot for the insight. And it might need processing since it uses django to select language translations that are code in files such as `django.po` so that a parameter can indicitate language i.e. `hl=el` for greek

Comment: OK, your home page could be a django script that redirects to one of every language you support (index_en.html, index_de.html, etc). You'll need to regen every hour for every different language, but that's not too much load for the server. The result will still be quicker than if you use a script to build every page.

Comment: excellent. I only require translations and those I can make with static html instead of django translations.